# Strange data point clustering in k-means

Tags: r, data-visualization, k-means

I am trying to explore weather impact on bike usage using k-means clustering. However, the plot does not look correct; visually, some data points obviously belong to another cluster that is closer than the centroid in which it is clustered to. Besides, two clusters seem to "overlap". Here are some info about the data and code (Count = number of bike trips):

[image: Info about data]

[image: Result of k-means clustering]

I am aware that I may have some outliers which I have not handled. This is because I do not know how to determine whether or not a point is an outlier. It would be appreciated if anyone could give me a concrete example of an outlier relevant to this scenario.
I have also looked into what is called correlation matrix and distance measure, but I do not know if that is relevant.

What could be the issue?

Comment: I think the issues are because you plot the high dimensional data in a low 2-dimensional graph.

Comment: If that is the case, how could I solve it? Thanks for the input!

Comment: It looks like Dim 1 & 2 are accounting for ~444% of the differences.  Either reduce the number of variables used to calculated distance or plot using different dimensions.

Comment: @Dave2e I see. I used a correlation matrix to look for variables that were highly correlated, and found that Cloud.cover and Conditions had a correlation of 0.46 which makes sense. Should I remove either of them? My general question about correlation matrix is: when should I consider removing variable(s) that correlate strongly? Thank you for your advice and help!

Comment: Hi @JessicaQuach, what Dave2e meant was, you have done the clustering on dataset.scaled which has some 10+ variables, and when you project your data on a pca, it is dimension reduced, meaning it tries to capture the most major variance in your original data

Comment: So, let's say there are 5 features / variables that are separating clusters 1,2,3 but are not weighed heavily in PC1 and PC2, then you will not see the separation. It really depends on the aim of what you want from the clustering. You can also do a boxplot or heatmap for all your clusters, to see what is defining each cluster

Comment: @StupidWolf So if I get it right, this graph is only showing PC1 and PC2 which sums up to ~45% of the differences. Is that good/bad? As for the "aim of what I want from the clustering", this is an exploratory analysis, aiming to find out weather impact on bike usage. How do I boxplot/heatmap the clusters? Apologies if this is a frequently asked question, you could just refer to an existing post/answer if you cannot provide a code example. I have not found any examples on my own. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Hi @JessicaQuach, sorry for the late reply. ```library(tidyr) ; library(ggplot2) ; clus = kmeans(iris[,-5],4); pivot_longer(data.frame(iris[,-5],clus=factor(clus$cluster)),-clus) %>% ggplot(aes(x=clus,y=value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~name) ```

Comment: This allows you to see for each variable, how the different clusters differ. Now for your dataset above, you will have a lot of variables.. you can plot a few at a time..